# Alternate for 'margin-top'? - CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fit a few navigation tabs onto an `<article>` tab but it doesn't work properly on firefox and when on different screens, it messes up. Does anyone know an alternative that works with all browsers and doesn't change as the screen is resized?

Here is the result I want:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/nnonhm0.jpg]

Exactly that except I don't want to use a fixed `margin-top`

**EDIT:**

Code:

Navigation:

```
nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4%;
}

nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav li {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #9A9489;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 11%;
    font: 1.4em/1.3em Bonveno, Open Sans, Sans-Serif;
    float: right;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 0.5%;
    border-top-left-radius: 0.3125em;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.3125em;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Article (without margin-top):

```
article {
    width: 99.5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0.3125em 0 #9A9489;
    padding: 0 0 0.5% 1.5%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <a href="contact.php">
            <li>Contact</li>
        </a>

        <a href="pictures.php">
            <li>Pictures</li>
        </a>

        <a href="about.php">
            <li class="selected">About</li>
        </a>

        <a link="black" href="index.php">
            <li>Home</li>
        </a>
    </ul>
</nav>

<article>
<h1>Hello World</h1>

<p>Hello world</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Show your code and perhaps an image of how it messes up. We can't fix what we can't see...

Comment: show us your current code or even better a fiddle

Comment: Impossible to answer without an example of your HTML. Also, it would be helpful to indicate what you've already tried, to make it clear **why** `margin-top` is not appropriate.

Comment: @Fabio, even better code PLUS a jsFiddle.  A jsFiddle should never be used here _in place of_ the code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but some HTML would be better. Can you explain why you don't want to use `margin-top`?

Comment: @Chris I showed my site to some people and some said to remove the fixed margin-top so that there was no space between the navs and the article this what they gave me to show: http://i.imgur.com/IICxys0.png

Comment: Can you include the HTML in your question? I wouldn't rule out `margin-top`, I am also not saying it is the solution. It just helps get a good answer if you explain statements like that/

Comment: @Sparky: SO wouldn't let him post a fiddle without code, so it went without saying, it's so obvious I didn't consider necessary to mention something he wouldn't be able to do

Comment: @Fabio, your original comment obviously only meant what it stated _"code OR a jsFiddle"_.   However, despite the automatic warning, users very often get around the posting requirement by including a small piece of inline code along with a jsFiddle link... so it never goes without saying.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can always try position as an alternative to margin.
In this case, I think you would have to use a relative position, so do the following:

```
.YOUR_TABS_SELECTOR{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
```